# OpenCV (Python) setMouseCallback preventing program termination

Tags: python, opencv

I have been writing a program in python using OpenCV. Up to this point, I had not set the mouse callback (cv2.setMouseCallback). To exit the program (which is in fullscreen), I would press the ESC key (Line 70).

I recently added a mouse callback (Line 11) which works as it should, however, now when I press the ESC key, the program does not terminate as it had previously. The while loop finishes, and cv2.destroyAllWindows() and sys.exit(0) are called. The window does close, and no python code after sys.exit(0) is executed, however no prompt is returned in Command Prompt (in which the python program was started).

My first thought was that there was a thread running that had not been stopped, however I have no threads in my code, and the thread that calls the onMouse function (Line 50) is the same as  the main loop thread (i.e. it would not appear that opencv has a seperate thread for mouse callbacks).

My code can be found here: http://pastie.org/9246511

I am stumped, and any help is greatly appreciated.

**Please note: You will need a webcam plugged in to test the code**

Comment: Are you running it in ipython?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, stock Python 2.7.6

Comment: I ran your code, the only way I could replicate your error is running in an ipython shell. what os are you using? Do you get the same behaviour using exit?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Win32, 64bit. I got exactly the same behaviour. I just ran it inside PyCharm, and the same issue. After pressing ESC the program appeared to finish, however PyCharm still reported the program as running.

Comment: Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: Here is an image of the program: http://i.imgur.com/kIgBfr2.png

Comment: In pycharm you don't get `Process finished with exit code 0`  after you press `esc`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No. It only returns an exit code after I forcibly stop it with the "Stop Process" button. The output is as follows: http://pastie.org/9246917

Comment: does  `os._exit(0)`  or  `sys.exit(1)`
do anything?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No. Same problem.

Comment: That is very strange, it must be a windows issue as I have tried running your script every possible way with no issues. You did not use sys.exit(0) and exit()? I see in your image you did, you should run all the suggestions by themselves NOT with sys.exit()

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have run all solutions independently. For now I can get around the problem, so it's not a big deal, but it would be nice to solve. Thanks for all your time!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to exit correctly running it as a script from a prompt and running in Pycharm when using `sys.exit()`.

If you are running it in `Ipython` you need to use `exit()` to return to the command prompt:

Just use  `exit()`  after `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` and it will terminate.

```
In [1]: type(exit)
Out[1]: IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately using exit() after cv2.destoryAllWindows() did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase you never got the answer...I just had the same issue.  Turns out it was because in my my config file (Run/Debug Configurations) I had checked the "Show command line afterwards" box.  Once I unchecked that the window was killed correctly.